# Horizontal stretch factor: what is the correct way?

Tags: functions

While at my summer school, I was taught that to translate a function, we should first isolate the `x`. Suppose the translated function is given by:

$$
y = 2f(\frac{1}{2}x + 1) + 3
$$

So, we can isolate the `x` like:

$$
y = 2f(\frac{1}{2}(x + 2)) + 3
$$

Now, here the horizontal stretch factor `s` = $\frac{2}{1}$ or $2$ and the horizontal translation is $-2$; the vertical stretch is $2$ and the vertical shift is $3$.

The problem is when I use these parameters to transform a point, the answer is wrong; however, if I use the parameters without taking $\frac{1}{2}$ common, the answer is correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give an example of the calculation you're doing for a particular function, and why you think it's wrong?

Comment: Taking the point (0, 0). HT = -2, Stretch = -4. x = -4
Y = 3  [-4, 3]

0 - 1 * 2 = -2
+3

[-2, 3]

See the difference.

Comment: I don't follow your calculation.  Please explain each step you're doing.  Edit it into the original question rather in the comments.